# Can't delete some files off of my HP home server

Tags: linux, smb, home-server

I have an HP Media Vault mv2120 (Linux based, not WHS based) and sometimes when I go to delete files that I added to the server, I get a message telling me that I need permission from Unix User Nobody to delete them. Why is this happening and how can I prevent it? So far when it happens, I have to ssh into the server (which was not enabled by default and I had to do some digging on Google to find out how to enable it) and delete them from there.

Comment: What distribution are you using? And is this a file already on it, or something you have just copied and loosing permission? - I got this a few times with my nas when I transfer files with large file names. To solve this, I either rename or delete using a web interface or ssh.

Comment: When I login I get the message: `BusyBox v1.01 (2008.02.08-22:41+0000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to take ownership of the files with [chown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) and possibly set permissions on the file(s) to 777 with [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

Since your server is linux based, you should be able to get the correct syntax with the `man` command.

Comment: Oh I was afraid of that. That's what I was doing, but I was hoping for a way to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Try setting the parent folder's ownership and permissions - that way, subsequent files that you place in that folder will inherit the parent's permissions.

Comment: I'll have to give that another shot.